# List webapplications in IIS with powershell

Tags: powershell, iis-8

The first sorry for my english, but I need your help with powershell scripting.
I must config IIS server with powershell script and I have problem with "add application". I need to check whether webapplication exist in site. I want 
choose all webapplication in site "testsite2"

```
$webapplication=Get-WebApplication | Where-Object {$_. applicationpool -eq "testsite2"} | select -expand Name;
```

But I have problem that command is ending with error

> select : Property "Name" cannot be found.At line:1 char:75  Get-WebApplication | Where-Object {$_. applicationpool -eq "testsite2"} | select ...  CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.IIs.P...gurationElement:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException  FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

I don´t understand. What have I do when I want choose value from column "Name"?

I get same result

```
Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools\ | Where-Object {$_. Name -eq "testsite2"} | select -ExpandProperty applications
```

result:

> select : Property "applications" cannot be found.
>   At line:1 char:80
>   Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools\ | Where-Object {$_. Name -eq "testsite2"} | s ...
>    CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.IIs.P...gurationElement:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
>       FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `WebAdministration` module can be a bit deceiving in that it uses custom formatting data to show stuff like `Name` with `Format-Table` (even though the underlying objects have no `Name` property).

To get the equivalent `Name` value, take the `Path` property and trim `/`:

```
$WebAppNames = Get-WebApplication |Select @{Name='Name';Expression={$_.Path.Trim('/')}} |Select -Expand Name
```

The above is exactly what the formatting subsystem in PowerShell does to calculate the `Name` value.

---

You can explore the actual properties an object has with the `Get-Member` cmdlet:

```
Get-WebApplication |Get-Member
```

This will also show you the type name, which you can use to explore any additional Type- or Format-Data that might apply:

```
Get-TypeData -TypeName 'Microsoft.IIS.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#site#application'
Get-FormatData -TypeName 'Microsoft.IIS.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#site#application'
```

Comment: I suggest you edit the answer to include get-member, to show how to find these actual properties ;)